# Retrieving json data in cakephp

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, itunes

I need to retrieve json output data from http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson

I am using cakephp 1.3.

Any idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.......");
$array = json_decode($json);

print_r($array);
```

Is that what you were looking for?
Should work :)

Comment: Hi Ofir, Thanks for posting your answer.

It works well. But how do I echo it in views?

Thanks again

Comment: $this->set('itunesData', $json);